# I tried going through the OpenVINO Integration with TensorFlow how to guide

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, intel, openvino

I went through the OpenVINO Integration with TensorFlow how to article and I feeling confused. Where was the tutorial in this? I am also not understanding that is OpenVINO worse than this product? Should we migrate from OpenVINO to this product. very confusing article.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are few examples that demonstrate how to use Intel® OpenVINO™ integration with Tensorflow package to recognize and detect objects in images and videos.

•   [Python Implementation for classification](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_tensorflow/tree/master/examples#python-implementation-for-classification)

•   [Python implementation for object detection](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_tensorflow/tree/master/examples#python-implementation-for-object-detection)

•   [C++ Implementation for classification](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_tensorflow/tree/master/examples#c-implementation-for-classification)

For more information, please refer to [OpenVINO™ integration with TensorFlow](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_tensorflow) GitHub Repository.